# Limit calculation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate this limit, but when I enter, the result is 0. But I don't think the result is 0, because every item here is greater than 1. So the result should not be 0, is the **Mathematica** something wrong?
[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, this appears to have been addressed in the version currently under development.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The version 12?  or others ?

Comment: I think it is in the upcoming 12.1 but not certain of that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround:

```
Limit[FunctionExpand[Product[1 + k/n, {k, 1, n}]], n -> Infinity]
```

> $\infty$

Addition. One more workaround

```
Limit[Sum[Log[1 + k/n], {k, 1, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

> $\infty$

Comment: Compare the outputs of                                                                 
            Product[1 + k/n, {k, 1, n}] $$\left.\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n (n+1)_n\right] $$ and  FunctionExpand[Product[1 + k/n, {k, 1, n}]] $$\frac{2^{2 n} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}.$$ I think the Limit command works better with the latter than the former.

Comment: I want to ask why you use the FunctionExpand

Comment: Thank you very much